# Mute/unmute iPhone based on location or time

Tags: iphone, sound-volume

My wife mutes her iPhone 5 at work because she has many landline phone meetings during the day and doesn't want the sound to play over her conference calls.  The problem is that she often doesn't unmute the phone when leaving work.  So, after leaving work, she will often miss calls or texts because she has muted the phone.

Is there any way to mute the phone on geographic location or time?  Ideally it would just mute within a mile of the office and unmute otherwise.  Alternatively, muting the phone 8-5 would work too, just as long as no action is needed to unmute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings > Do Not Disturb` has many options available, as [explained at this page](http://www.imore.com/how-to-setup-use-do-not-disturb-iphone-ipad):

[image]

or Apple's brief explanation [here](http://help.apple.com/iphone/8/#/iph3dd60e1f):

> **Do Not Disturb**
>
> Do Not Disturb is an easy way to silence iPhone, whether you’re going
>   to dinner or to sleep. It keeps calls and alerts from making any
>   sounds or lighting up the screen.
>
> Turn on Do Not Disturb. Swipe up from the bottom edge of the screen to
>   open Control Center, then tap the do not disturb button. When Do Not
>   Disturb is on, the do not disturb button appears in the status bar.
>
> Note: Alarms still sound, even when Do Not Disturb is on. To make sure
>   iPhone stays silent, turn it off.
>
> Configure Do Not Disturb. Go to Settings > Do Not Disturb.
>
> You can schedule quiet hours, allow calls from your Favorites or
>   groups of contacts, and allow repeated calls to ring through for those
>   emergency situations. You can also set whether Do Not Disturb silences
>   iPhone only when it’s locked, or even when it’s unlocked.

Its really quite handy, but what is lacking is the ability to schedule `Do Not Disturb` in the Calendar app for repeats and specific times of the day. That would be sweet.

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant information from the links into your answer, to prevent linkrot.

Answer (score 4):

I just saw this software on the App Store: [Auto Mute](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/auto-mute-by-location/id650303758?mt=8) by Niv Gutherz.  It's currently $.99US and I haven't used it so I can't indicate if it works or not.

From the app description:

> AutoMute allows you to automatically mute,un-mute your iPhone,iPad on selected locations.  In addition it will allow you to automatically change your iPhone, iPad volume to minimum or maximum on selected locations.  Automatically mute your phone at cinema, at the library and any other locations that you want to silence your phone.
>
> Don't forget to un-mute your phone when you leave those locations and miss important calls.  AutoMute will automatically un-mute your iPhone,iPad when you leave those locations.
>
> Uses minimum battery power. Uses iDevice region monitoring with low battery usage.